# NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

in my application when i run app for first time,it work ok.but when i run again 2 two times, it crashes.

This is the error..

NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array'

[image]

[image]

Comment: `arrMydata` array seems to be empty. Thats what the crash log tells.

Comment: arrMydata should be alloc] init 'ed or it should have arrayWithCapacity://somevalue before adding object to arrMydata

Comment: @2-Stroker i know but i cant find solution.

Comment: @JohnDoe yes  arrMydata allock]init is there.any solution ?

Comment: Have you added any objects to your array ? Can you show that code

Comment: yes i added object to array..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Reason:** You are accessing Empty array about to access object at index.

replace all places like in your code below

```
[arrMydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with

```
 //1. Positive index ([anArray objectAtIndex:-NUMBERS]) will crash

 //2. within the array boundary

 if([arrMydata count] > 0 && [arrMydata count] > indexPath.row){

    shrObj=[arrMydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 }
 else{

    //Array is empty,handle as you needed

 }
```

[**Here You can see the non software example, which will explain this issue. Good luck! **](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24407937/675170)

Comment: I think , just this `[arrMydata count] > inxexPath.row` check is enough.

Comment: to have 1. Positive index

Comment: //1. Positive index ([anArray objectAtIndex:-NUMBERS]) will crash

Comment: I accept with that. But indexPath.row always positive, then why need that check? Is there any scenario for getting negative indexPath?

Comment: You can create NSIndexPath as alone as well and pass it to it. Procedure way to avoid crash is like that.

Comment: No one wouldn't create NSIndexPath for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]

Comment: @Supertecnoboff if you want the non software example, please review here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24407937/675170 . Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You array is empty, but you're trying to access an object in it. That is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Reason:** According to your log, you're trying to access empty array. Just fix this by below code

```
if (arrMydata.count > inxexPath.row)
    sharObj = [arrMydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone : in my case the array was not in code, but an IB outlet that was an array of 5 UIImageViews in the storyboard.

@IBOutlet var upAndDownArrowImages: [UIImageView]!

Reason for the crash was that I mistakenly deleted 1 of those UIImageViews from the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it Crashes for `heightForRowAt indexpath`, Do check this method for smooth operation.

Hope it Helps someone.