# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm developing apps using web services I got this error like this it was happen when I test the real devices but when I run the retina 3.5 simulator it works perfectly please help me I have tried but I cannot fix this.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30b59fd3 0x3b308ccf 0x30a9081b 0xeec19 0x334a8917 0x3344fc47 0x3344f49d 0x33375d79 0x32ff362b 0x32feee3b 0x32feeccd 0x32fee6df 0x32fee4ef 0x33379401 0x30b2525b 0x30b2472b 0x30b22f1f 0x30a8df0f 0x30a8dcf3 0x35992663 0x333d916d 0x100ec1 0x3b815ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Code :

```
-(void)loaddetails
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/news/headlines?apikey=th98vzm67pufc36ka42xxxmy"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSDictionary *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

    NSArray *headlinetop=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"headlines"];

    for (int i=0; i<[headlinetop count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *headstr=[[headlinetop objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"headline"];
        [loadingcell addObject:headstr];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

    }
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10.0, 250, 26.0)];
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    title.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Hebrew" size:15.0];
    title.text=[loadingcell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show your code, find which line does it crash. Your array is empty, and somewhere you're doing `[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]`.

Comment: Post the symbolicated stacktrace and the relevant code.

Comment: You're trying to access an array that is empty. Likely your web service isn't retiring anything but you are still trying to access the results.

Comment: DON'T SHOW US CODE IN COMMENTS.  Edit your question to add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding the concept of accessing the array object, here i came up with the example which explains clearly why its crashing when you access the object at index in array.

I'm not going to pointout where you did mistakes. understand the concept and based on that change the code whereever you have like `[yourArray objectAtIndex:10]`.

**Non Software example:**

You have bag(NSMutableArray) which has 10 balls labeled from (0,1,2...9), but how would you find out the 11th ball. Not Possible!.

1.First you should have bag in your hand readily.(`[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`)

2.Then try to access it.

3.Your problem here is you are looking for first ball(0th labeled) inside the bag . iOS says "Sorry"

```
//assume [array count] == 10 (0,1,2,3,4,5,...9)

NSUInteger indexTobeAccessedInArray = 5;//6th object (0,1,2,3,4,5,...9)


if (array && [array count]>0) {
    // array lives in memory and it has atleast one objects in it

    // 5 < 10
    if (indexTobeAccessedInArray < [array count]) {
        //Yes
        NSLog(@"you can access this index:%i",indexTobeAccessedInArray);

    }
    else{
        //No
        NSLog(@"Index %i beyond bounds for array",indexTobeAccessedInArray);

    }

}
else{
    // There was no array in memory
    NSLog(@"sorry there is no array, you should create & initialize it first like \n NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]");

}
```

Comment: thank you for gave the info about the arrays but i can able to access the array here before but now its show the empty

Comment: If anyone downvoted my answer, I would appreciate if you could add some comments. So that i will try to rectify myself. Thanks to anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing:

```
id myObject = [myArray firstObject];
if(nil != myObject)
{
    // Do something
}
```

But without showing us the code, I can't really suggest anymore.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the count instead of if the array is nil.

Comment: NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/boxing/news/headlines?apikey=th98vzm67pufc36ka42xxxmy"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSDictionary *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

Comment: NSArray *headlinetop=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"headlines"];
    
    for (int i=0; i<[headlinetop count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *headstr=[[headlinetop objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"headline"];
        [loadingcell addObject:headstr];

Comment: a UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10.0, 250, 26.0)];
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    
    title.text=[loadingcell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick with number of rows delegate method..If loadingcell array is empty. Then cell will load with empty rows..

```
loadingcell=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//check that you initialized and allocated loadingcell
```

Modify your code as below..

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
        return loadingcell.count;
      }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

        if (cell == nil) 
        { 
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

        }
        if(loadingcell.count>0)
        {
          UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10.0, 250, 26.0)]; title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
          title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; 
          title.textColor=[UIColor blackColor]; title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Hebrew" size:15.0]; 
          title.text=[loadingcell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
          [cell.contentView addSubview:title]; 
          if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
          { 
             cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; 
          }
        }

        return cell; 
   }
```

Hope it helps you..