# i got error while i open Paypal in iOS 9.0,.but it working on ios 7 and 8

Tags: ios, paypal

while I open Paypal for Payment Gateway in iOS 9 my app is crashed but its working on iOS 7 & 8.
How to fix it?

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '-[NSTaggedPointerString getCharacters:range:]: Range {0, 7} out of
>   bounds; string length 6'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSRangeException', reason: '\*\*\* -\[\_\_NSArrayM objectAtIndex:\]: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423473/nsrangeexception-reason-nsarraym-objectatindex-index-5-beyond-bou)

Comment: Please post some code for your help.

Comment: i tried new paypal sdk but its size is very high(445 MB)

Answer (score 0):

have you download new framework from PayPal Developer site?
If yes then it use below code:

```
    self.completedPayment = nil;
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Products *product in appDelegate.arrCartItems) {
        PayPalItem *item1 = [PayPalItem itemWithName:product.productName
                                        withQuantity:[product.productSST intValue]
                                           withPrice:[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[product.productSP floatValue]]]
                                        withCurrency:@"USD"
                                             withSku:@"Photos & Videos-00037"];
        //                        NSArray *items = @[item1];
        [items addObject:item1];
    }
    //                float orderPrice = [orderTotal floatValue];
    //                NSLog(@"orderPrice: %f",orderPrice);


    NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [PayPalItem totalPriceForItems:items];
    // Optional: include payment details
    NSDecimalNumber *shipping = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"50.00"];
    NSDecimalNumber *tax = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0.00"];
    PayPalPaymentDetails *paymentDetails = [PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetailsWithSubtotal:subtotal
                                                                               withShipping:shipping
                                                                                    withTax:tax];

    NSDecimalNumber *totalAmount = [[subtotal decimalNumberByAdding:shipping] decimalNumberByAdding:tax];

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = totalAmount;
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = @"Item Details";
    payment.items = items;  // if not including multiple items, then leave payment.items as nil
    payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails; // if not including payment details, then leave payment.paymentDetails as nil

    if (!payment.processable) {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
        // to handle that here.
    }

    // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
    self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = self.acceptCreditCards;

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                                configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                     delegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i already try this code but app is still crashed in [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: can u pls paste here error log... or ur code to present paypal

Comment: i got below error msg-
NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array' 
but now i used Paypal 2.13.0 is still working but new SDK size is very high