# Pull to refresh resulting app to crash: NSRangeException, reason: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

Sorry if this has been asked before but I can't find the answer to my problem.

I wrote code for pull to refresh but it crashed IF the result array count is different from the `indexPath.row` and I've tried to remove my array objects yet it's still crash.

my code goes for this:

```
-(void)loadMore:(id) sender {
    loadFlag = 1;
    NSString *employeeID = @"aaa";
    days = 3;

    int projIDNum = 1234;
    int depCode = 1234000001;
    int caseNum = 45678;
    NSString *result = [client report_search:employeeID case_no:caseNum status:loadFlag 
        day:days project_id:projIDNum dep_code:depCode count:10];
    if ([result isEqualTo:@"[]"]) {
        [Utilities callAlert:self title:@"No More Data" body:@"There is no other data contains"];
        [refresh endRefreshing];
    } else {
        NSData *jsonData = [result dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *error;
        [resultArr removeAllObjects];
        // resultArr is NSMutableArray and it's the tableview's data source
        resultArr = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: 0 
            error:&error] mutableCopy];
        [refresh endRefreshing];
        [_mSearchTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

If I get full 10 data result, the program itself won't crash but it happens when I get less than 10 datas from web service.  I kept getting this exception, `NSRangeException, reason: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]` but don't know how to deal with it.

My tableview setting:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) table:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [resultArr count];
}
```

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath – Tj3n

```
-(UITableViewCell) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // clear cell
    for ([UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    } else {
        titleLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    }

    CGRect location = CGRectMake(20, 20, 71/75, 40/146);
    titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:location];
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
    titleLabel.text = [resultArr valueForKey:@"title"][indexPath.row];  // this is the line always crashed
    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

also updating my json:

```
print out result: [
    {
    Content = "Test\nTest\n";
    "Create_Datetime" = "2016-09-12 10:18:25";
    "Project_ID" = 2023;    
    Status = 4;    
    "CASE_NO" = 17704;
    Title = "Table title";
    "Update_Datetime" = "2016-09-12 10:19:09";
},
    {
    Content = "Fhujhfdfhjoookbvv\nGu...";
    "Create_Datetime" = "2016-09-12 10:09:28";
    "Project_ID" = 2023;
    Status = 4;
    "CASE_NO" = 17703;
    Title = "Table title";
    "Update_Datetime" = "2016-09-12 10:12:59";
},
    {
    Content = dafsdfasfasfas;
    "Create_Datetime" = "2016-09-04 01:52:09";
    "Project_ID" = 2023;
    Status = 5;
    "CASE_NO" = 16512;
    Title = "Table title";
    "Update_Datetime" = "2016-09-14 16:44:46";
},
    {
    Content = dafsdfa;
    "Create_Datetime" = "2016-09-04 01:41:59";
    "Project_ID" = 2023;
    Status = 4;
    "CASE_NO" = 16511;
    Title = "Table title";
    "Update_Datetime" = "2016-09-04 01:42:23";
},
    {
    Content = sdfasfasf;
    "Create_Datetime" = "2016-09-02 14:14:39";
    "Project_ID" = 2023;
    Status = 2;
    "CASE_NO" = 16502;
    Title = "Table title Table subtitle";
    "Update_Datetime" = "2016-09-02 15:17:50";
}]
```

**UPDATE:**
I've tried to print out the log for the array count in different places before crash.

First place is `before table reload` and the number of objects in the array is 5.

Second place is in the `cellForRowsAtIndexpath`.  I had 2 items to print out

1. total count of the resultArr is 5, which is consist with the array
   count before reload.
2. the current indexpath.row.  The odd thing happened in here is that **it's at 8th cell rather than 5th**.

Lastly, the place I print out log is at `numberOfRowsInSection`.  Before the app crashed, it does not print out the log.

Comment: post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: update has been posted

Comment: You dont need to clear cell but it seems normal, can you set breakpoint and see which line causing the crash?

Comment: sorry I wasn't being clear about my description
`titleLabel.text = [resultArr valueForKey:@"title"][indexPath.row];` this line is where it cause the crash.  I kept getting my indexPath.row has total of 0 .. 8
but in fact it should be 0 .. 4

Comment: You are getting the wrong item in that line, thats why it cause crash, is `[resultArr valueForKey:@"title"]` is an array?

Comment: resultArr is the JSON array I got from the web service and it was string so I convert into array

Comment: I'm not sure what's your resultArr structure, so for the problem gone you can try change your `numberOfRows` to `[[resultArr valueForKey:@"title"] count]` to match the code in your `cellForRow`

Comment: I have also test your method and it still crashed

Comment: I guess you should post the resultArr here so that I can learn it structure, you said it's array but you use valueForKey with it, so it should be dictionary

Comment: Change back your code in numberOfRows, and change the one in your cellForRow to `[resultArr indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Title"]`

Comment: it's still crash at the same line

Comment: make sure it have value by print out `[resultArr indexPath.row]` and it's key

Comment: it's crashing when calling the `resultArr[indexPath.row]`
I also print out the indexPath of the time it crashed 
`print out the indexpath: <NSIndexPath: 0x7a07bd80> {length = 2, path = 0 - 8}`

Comment: print `resultArr ` before `reloadTable` and see the structure

Comment: it is the exact content that I have posted at the above. in that array it contains 5 datas

Comment: that's really strangle....i cant see what's the problem, it's just the number of the rows and the indexpath must be the same

Comment: I know....
that's why I am seeking help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423473/nsrangeexception-reason-nsarraym-objectatindex-index-5-beyond-bou?rq=1)

Thank you, JingJingTao and Tj3n for helping me out.

I finally found the answer for this bug but I still can't figure out why and the cause for this one.  From logic, it should go to `numberOfRowsInSection` first to setup the number of row for current table but apparently it did not.  Can someone care to explain why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I think something is going wrong with how you get the title, instead of `titleLabel.text = [resultArr valueForKey:@"title"][indexPath.row];`, could you try the following. If this does not work, could you print out what that value is for each i.e. what the value of 'dictionary' and 'title' are.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [resultArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"]; 
titleLabel.text = title;
```

Comment: sorry for such a late reply...
I had some other business need to take care of first.  
sorry I can't reveal more because I was doing for commercial  project, that I don't want to reveal much details.  
I've tried with your method and yet it still crashed

Comment: no worries, can you check that [resultArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; is a dictionary and [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"] is a string? If you use my three lines at which line does it crash?

Comment: it crashed at first line with the same reason.  
I feel the `tableviewcell` is creating more than the array and yet I can't find the reasons for it

Comment: if you set a breakpoint at the first line, the indexpath.row is 8 or it basically goes to values greater than 4? Also you might have said before, is the numberOfRowsForSection always 4, set a breakpoint and check. You can also try using 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:' instead of 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:'

Comment: Yes, it is a dictionary indeed and when I can extract out the content within the dictionary. Another thing about this odd bug is that it's not happening all the time. It happened ONLY when SOMETIME I load the remaining data from web service

Comment: You say numberOfRowsInSection does not print anything when the app crashes, set a breakpoint in that method and print out the count of resultArr or even just po resultArr

Comment: I tested out and found before it runs `numberOfRowsInSection` it runs `cellForRowsAtIndexpath` for about 5 times and during those 5 times, it is between 0-2.  After that it begin to run  `numberOfRowsInSection`  and back to `cellForRowsAtIndexpath` for the rest of data.

Comment: it will always do numberOfRowsInSection first, so initially it's 5 and then cellForRowsAtIndexpath is obviously called 5 times, I'm trying to figure out the state of resultArr during the reload, unfortunately it's tricky to figure what you problem is without seeing more code or even debugging your project, could you show where you call loadMore? How many times is numberOfRowsInSection called after reloadData is called?

Comment: loadMore is called at pull to refresh and numberOfRowsInSection called once after loadMore has been called.